# Gradle's dependency cache seems to be corrupt or out of sync

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting this error while upgrading my Android Studio from 3.6.x to 4.0
After upgrading I got a prompt asking to upgrade my gradle version to 6.1.1

So my gradle-wrapper.property file changed from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

to

```
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

and my build.gradle file dependencies classpath changed from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
```

to

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
```

After this when I do a gradle sync I get this following error

Things I have tried:

1. Checking the dist URL from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ which matches
2. Deleting the .gradle cache
3. Manually adding gradle-6.1.1-all file in the .gradle > wrapper> dist folder
4. Invalidate cache and restart

Nothing seems to make this error go away . But if I revert back my gradle version and plugin version to 5.6.4 and 3.6.3 the gradle sync works.

Comment: Can you tell us the error message?

Comment: @12rhombiingridwnocorners The error message I used to get was: 
**Gradle's dependency cache seems to be corrupt or out of sync.Re download dependencies and sync Project**. Actually nothing worked from my list . After project clean the Gradle sync worked successfully

Comment: Check that you don't have gradle running in offline mode.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Invalidate Cache and restart doesn't work try  Build > Clean project